# Php convert only quotes to html code but not other special chars

Tags: php, html, quotes

So i have in my mysql 
`'UAB "Litofc&#371; kontora"'`

When i try to put it in input like this

`<input type="text" value="UAB "Litofc&#371; kontora"">` it don't display whole thing because of the quotes how to make that only quotes replace with a html code?
tried htmlentities and htmlspecialchars but it converts `&#371;` to but i need that to be the way it's don't covert.

Answer (score 0):

You have (only) to replace all `"` with `&quot;` before outputing the *input value*. E.g. with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$sInputValue = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $sValueFromDb);
echo '<input type="text" value="' . $sInputValue . '">';
```

Also see [this php exmaple](http://ideone.com/cq9YB) and [the resulting html example](http://jsfiddle.net/n8yRR/).

Comment: @Pekka: I never said (and analyzed) that there is a problem with `htmlspecialchars()` (I said _"e.g."_). There're several ways to solve the problem.

Comment: @user1487699: have you seen my examples and tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that the data has been encoded for HTML but only for use as a text node.

The solution therefore is to convert it from HTML to text, and then convert it back to HTML - but in a fashion suitable for putting in an attribute.

`preg_replace_callback` code from [this comment in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php#104617) because `html_entity_decode` appears to not support numeric entities.

```
$input = 'UAB "Litofc&#371; kontora"';
$attribute_safe = htmlspecialchars(
        html_entity_decode(
            preg_replace_callback(
                "/(&#[0-9]+;)/",
                function($m) { return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); },
                $input
            )
        )
);
echo $attribute_safe;
```

Comment: @scessor — That's why the string is *decoded* from HTML to text first… except that doesn't seem to be working properly…

Comment: it shows that letter ų in code only i want to see it normaly.

Comment: WTF? Based on the comments in on the documentation page, html_entity_decode only operates on *named* entities. Every time I learn something new about PHP, I hate it some more.